# React Javascript, universal Header remove for Dashboard Site

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, header

I have a website, the header with the router function is on the "/" and I want to use another new header in the dashboard. So I want the header to be available to normal people on all pages, but in the dashboard it is invisible and another header is in the dashboard.

The Function:

```
<Route path='/' component={HeaderComponent} />
```

Comment: If you want a component to be there regardless of the route then add your component outside of the router components. We can't help you further since there is not enough information here to help

Answer (score 0):

You may created nested routes for

1. **/**

```
<Route exact path='/'>
   <Header/>
   // Other components or Routes
</Route>
```

2. **/dashboard**

```
<Route exact path='/dashboard'>
   <DashboardHeader/>
   // Other components or Routes
</Route>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The normal header is still there

Comment: You will also need to wrap routers with <Switch>
And I edited the code above (I forgot to add 'exact')